# How get an attribute in Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am new to the development in Capybara,Rspec using Ruby. How to get an attribute from the given HTML tags?

e.g. the HTML code is looking like this:

```
<li id="123" class="exestep">
```

How to get ID value by giving class name using Capybara. First of all is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) to find an element via XPath or CSS and [`Element#[]`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#%5B%5D-instance_method) to retrieve the id:

```
it 'retrieves the id' do
  id = find('.exestep')[:id]
  expect(id).to eq('123')
end
```